# Please help me to understand this differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a DE:

$\tau \cdot \frac{\delta e_o^2(t)}{\delta t}+e_o^2(t) = e_i^2(t)$

I know that $e_i^2=E^2_{{i}_{RMS}}\cdot(1+cos(2\omega t))$

where t is time and $\tau$ is a constant.

I'm told the particular solution of the DE is:

$e_o^2(t) = E^2_{{i}_{RMS}}\cdot[1+ \frac{sin(2\omega t + \phi)}{[1+(2\omega\tau)^2]^{0.5}}]$

but I can't for the life of me figure out how to get there, I've tried going through many different ways but I never seem to get the answer. Can anyone kick me in the right direction ?

PS - it comes from this paper - https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6312421

Comment: 1. The paper is unavailable. 2. Why not simply check that the proposed solution solves the differential equation?

Comment: Strange, the paper is available for me. The solution is correct and works, I would like to be able to get to the answer myself, I'm doing this as a learning exercise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an ODE
$$
τu'+u=R(1+\cos(2ωt))
$$
The non-exponential part of the general solution has the form $u(t)=A+B\cos(2ωt)+C\sin(2ωt)$. Insert into the equation
$$
-2ωτB\sin(2ωt)+2ωτC\cos(2ωt)+A+B\cos(2ωt)+C\sin(2ωt)=R(1+\cos(2ωt))\\
\implies
\left\{\begin{aligned}
-2ωτB+C&=0\\
2ωτC+B&=R\\
A&=R
\end{aligned}\right.
$$
so that $(B-iC)(1+2ωτi)=R$. Putting this in polar coordinates gives $B-iC=\frac{R}{\sqrt{1+(2ωτ)^2}}e^{i\phi}$. With this definition of the phase factor, the solution is
$$
u(t)=R\left(1+\frac{\cos(2ωt+ϕ)}{\sqrt{1+(2ωτ)^2}}\right).
$$
Using a different definition of the phase gives the form in the paper.

---

Or starting directly with complex-valued functions, observe that $u=e_o^2$ is the real part of the solution of
$$
τz'+z = R(1+e^{i2ωt})
$$
so that again the stable part of the solution has the form $z=A+Be^{i2ωt}$ and inserting this leads to
$$
i2ωτBe^{i2ωt}+A+Be^{i2ωt} = R(1+e^{i2ωt})
\implies
\left\{\begin{aligned}
(1+i2ωτ)B &= R\\
A &= R
\end{aligned}\right.
$$
and using polar coordinates for $B$ leads to the same solution as above.

Comment: Thank you so much! It might take me a while to digest this, and I'm sure I'll have more questions later on, but I'll mark this as the answer :) Thanks again!

Comment: Can I ask how you knew what the general solution to the the non-exponential part was? I "solved" this via a different method, and got: $e_o = \frac{R}{i \tau \omega + \tau}$ Is this at all close to your answer ?

Comment: Just seen your new edit, looks like how I was trying to derive it, so I will take a deeper look